# Holding / Possessing / Earning / Attaining a degree

Tags: word-usage

I would like to say "people hold a university degree". Can I paraphrase it as "people earned/possess/own a uni degree"? 
Also is it possible to say "He attained/achieved a higher degree of education than the others?" 
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Can you say "people hold/possess/earned/own a university degree? Are all these forms correct?

Comment: I wouldn't use "own", which implies *property*: can you sell/trade/transfer a degree? PS please [edit] your post to correct it as per @jsw29's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several questions here.

**(1)** Can one replace *hold a university degree* with *has earned a university degree*?

Yes, the two terms are interchangeable, insofar as one holds a degree if and only if one has earned it (setting aside some highly unusual scenarios). The two terms, however, direct the attention of the audience in subtly different directions. If one uses *hold*, one is focusing on the **present**, on the fact that the person has the degree now, and is thus, for example, qualified to take some job. If one uses *has earned*, one focuses on the **past**, on the process of working towards the degree (it may thus be a particularly apt term to use if one is describing how hard somebody worked to get the degree).

**(2)** Can one replace *hold a university degree* with *possess a university degree*?

Yes, one would be readily understood if one used *possess*. It is, however, not clear why one would want to do that; *hold* is likely to sound better in most contexts.

**(3)** Can one replace *hold a university degree* with *own a university degree*?

No, using *own* would be awkward, for the reason pointed out by Chappo in the comments. Saying that something is owned would normally be understood to imply that it can be bought and sold.

**(4)** Can one say 'He attained/achieved a higher degree of education than the others'?

Yes, but is should be noted that *degree* has a different meaning there than in the other questions. One can speak of 'a higher degree of education' even in a context that deals with informal education, in which no degrees (in the sense in which the word is used in (1)-(3)) are awarded.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot jsw29. I really appreciate your detailed answer!